# Numerical Integration of a multi-dimensional integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to perform a numerical integration as part a computing matrix elements for a given block diagonal matrix. I've been trying different several approaches with NIntegrate but none have been successful and are really slow. I know for a fact the eigenvalues of the matrix are all order one numbers but with the following code I get extremely small eigenvalues. The matrix is defined as follows:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\int f_k^*Wf_{k'} & 0\\
0 & \int g_k^*Wg_{k'}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Here is the code:

```
f[u_, v_, k_] := E^(-I k u) - E^(-I k v);
g[u_, v_, k_] := E^(-I k u) + E^(-I k v);
W[u_, v_, p_, q_, ϵ_] := -1/(4 π)Log[-(0.0116681)^2 (u - p - I ϵ) (v - q - I ϵ)];

Int[k_, m_] =
  f[-x, -y, (k π)/l] W[u, v, x, y, 10^-2] f[u, v, (m π)/l] // FullSimplify
Int2[k_, m_] = 
  g[-x, -y, (k π)/l] W[u, v, x, y, 10^-2] g[u, v, (m π)/l] // FullSimplify

Mat[k_, m_] :=  
  NIntegrate[Int[k, m], {u, -1, 0, 1}, {v, -1, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 0, 1}, 
                        {y, -1, 0,1}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
Mat2[k_, m_] :=  
  NIntegrate[Int2[k, m], {u, -1, 0, 1}, {v, -1, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 0, 1}, 
                         {y, -1, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

The $k$ values range from 0 to 2500, but even a single integration for example

```
Mat[30,30]
```

takes really long. And with small $k$ values ($k<50$)  I get

> Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

I have used the same code to construct a matrix with ($k>300$) but when computing the eigenvalues I get really small numbers which means something is very wrong. I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: 3D integrals often are quite slow, but you can speed the computation some by combining the various functions into a single expression for each integrand.

Comment: Did you try Monte-Carlo, it usually works better for the multidimensional problems.

Comment: I have tried Montecarlo without success. Maybe I have used it naively and that is why It failed (?). Perhaps you can give me tips on what MC routine to use and with what configurations so I can try it and see if it works @SvyatoslavKorneev .